# How to create new branch and merges differences from another branch into it with exception of a single directory

Tags: git

I have a branch that I did a bunch of Rubocop changes to (called dev/rubocop-changes). I'd like to create a branch (called dev/rubocop-changes-no-app) that takes all the changes from this with the exception of changes in the /app directory (ie /spec, / etc....).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a way to do it :

1) Creating the new branch from your main trunk (let's assume dev here for the example)

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b dev/rubocop-changes-no-app
```

---

2) Taking all your changes from the Rubocop branch (but preventing the merge from finishing)

```
git merge --no-commit dev/rubocop-changes
```

---

3) Rewinding the /app directory back to the state it was before the merge

```
git checkout dev -- /app/*
```

---

4) Then finishing the merge commit

```
git commit -am "merge commit message here"
```